# how to fix "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No element found in 'only'" in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to select a value from DB in Kotlin but getting "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No element found in 'only'" error.

I have written a class and and I have used map as RowMapper

```
class MarketplaceGetEffectiveRateQuery(private val handle: Handle) {


    fun run(resourceUUID: UUID,subscriptionUuid: UUID): BigDecimal {
       return handle.createQuery(GET_EFFECTIVE_RATE_QUERY)
            .bind("resourceUUID", resourceUUID)
                .bind("ms_subscription_id", subscriptionUuid)
            .map(EffectiveRateMapper())
                .findOnly()
    }
}
```

```
   override fun map(rs: ResultSet, ctx: StatementContext): BigDecimal {
       return rs.getBigDecimal("effective_rate")
    }
}
```

Comment: Add full stack trace, please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are using [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/). 
If so then this is absolutely correct behavior

```
public interface ResultIterable<T> extends Iterable<T> { 

     /**
     * Get the only row in the result set.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if zero or multiple rows are returned
     * @return the object mapped from the singular row in the results
     */
    default T findOnly() { ... }
}
```

Note @throws IllegalStateException **if zero or multiple** rows are returned

Hence you should only use `findOnly()` when you are absolutely sure that a query always produces a single result